# Deploy API based app on any store

Tags: android, git, rest, google-play, sails.js

I'm currently developping an app with the ionic framework (for the client side) and sails.js (for the server side).

I have a dedicated server which is used to host the server side on, lets say, `myapp.com` , and all is under git versionning

So, for exemple, when I want to login, I query `myapp.com/signin` which answer `true` or `false` (that's a very basic exemple).

I publish my app in production, wait a couple of hours, and my app is available to all.

But now, I want my server to answer `{success: true, token: xxxxxx}` instead of the basic `true` or `false`. I push my server modifications, which take effects instantly, but I still have to wait a couple of hours for my recently updated application to be approved. So, all the currently users can't use the application, because the server side and client side doesn't 'match'

I don't really know where to begin to avoid this. Do you have any experience on it, or any idea on how to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should version your API.

Example: 
For your next app version instead of requesting `myapp.com/signin` it would request `myapp.com/v2/signin`.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, but does it involve to have multiple instance of my nodejs server running ?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with nodejs so I'm not sure. Perhaps post a separate question for this.

Comment: Well, it's at least a way to explore ! :-)